# Discord.js v13 bot won't join voice channels

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Been troubleshooting this for multiple hours now. Issue is that I don't get any error logs from this as the code runs "fine". The bot just doesn't join a voice channel. I have copied the code almost 1:1 from a YouTube tutorial where it worked, and I have tried the official Discord guides as well, and both have the same results.

Here's my code:

```
const discordVoice = require('@discordjs/voice');

const player = discordVoice.createAudioPlayer();
const resource = discordVoice.createAudioResource(`/sounds/happy/${happySoundsRandom}`);
                    
const connection = discordVoice.joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: channel.id,
  guildId: message.guild.id,
  adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
                        
player.play(resource);
connection.subscribe(player);

console.log("Bot sent to voice")
```

When I run that by sending a message, I do get that console.log but no results on Discord side. I have readded the bot as an administrator, and made 100% sure the bot has voice channel permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `message.member.voice.channel.id` instead of your `channel.id`

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately. EDIT: It does now, but my bot joins as deafened...

Comment: That's a quick fix. In the JoinVoiceChannel object. Add a property selfDeaf, and set the value of selfDeaf to false. "selfDeaf : false".